# over and partition statement in TSQL / SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following sql statement delete duplicate records from a given table `tab`. This works as expected. Can someone brief me on the `over, partition` statements and how it works in sql server or any server on that matter.

```
with cte as (
  select c1, c2, c3,c4,c5,row_number() over (partition by c1, c2, c3,c4 order by id) as [rn]
  from [xxx].[dbo].[tab]
)
delete cte where [rn] > 1;
```

Comment: The correct term for this is "window function"

Comment: Btw: I like the tutorial on window functions in the Postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: [see here for one such example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716139/quick-help-using-rank-over-multiple-variables)

Comment: In your case, the table uniqueness is defined by the combination of `c1`, `c2`, `c3` and `c4`. Therefore, the windewed function is partitioning based on this `composite key` and increments the `sequence number` by one, if it finds any duplicates. In your particular example, all records with `row_number()>1` are considered as duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over (partition by ...) is basically a group by, applied only on that one column. So, what you're doing is:

select a few rows, and then select a row_number that:
Starts anew for each combination of c1, c2, c3 and c4, and shows a row number ordered based on the id column (of all the items in that particular combination).